# What is wrong with this css code for relative positioning w.r.t. parent?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

Here's a problem that is bugging me notoriously. I've created following html & css codes:

### HTML

```
<div class="hi">
    <img alt="This shuould be an image" src="Images/img1.jpg">
    <div class="ihi">
      <img alt="This shuould be inside of main image" src="Images/img2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

### CSS

```
.hi img{
  position:absolute;
  left:25%;
  top:0%;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
}
.ihi img{
  position:absolute;
  left:25%;
  top:25%;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
}
```

The parent element of course displays as required but the problem appears for the child element. The child element with class 'ihi' is always positioning w.r.t. the browser window instead of the parent image having class 'hi'. Setting the position of the parent 'relative' also did not work. I have also tested the code in multiple browsers like chrome, edge, opera etc. but the problem still remains.Please tell me what is exactly going here. Thanks is advance.

Comment: Setting the parent to anything else than static is definitly working.

Comment: The problem is that `.ihi` is not a child of `.hi img`, it's a child of `.hi` - so the styles you applied to `.hi img` are irrelevant when calculating the styles of `.ihi` or `.ihi img` (because `.ihi` is a sibling of the styled element, not a child).

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood... What I understood was that you want the first image to be 50% of the width of the window and 100% of the height of the window with it's left side 25% away from the left side of the window. Then you want the second image to be 50%, width and height, of the first image's size with its left edge 25% away from the left side of the first image. This is what I attempted to create with my answer. Is this wrong?

Comment: @JonUleis Thanks for pointing that out. Your suggestion solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Uleis mentioned, the first image is not the parent of the second. Actually, an image can't contain another element. So, I don't think you can use CSS to position the second image with regard to the first image.

I think you can get the desired effect by positioning the div that contains both images in the way you wanted to position the first image. Then just make the first image 100% width and height. You don't even need to position the first image. Then set the position and size on the second image the way you wanted to...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.hi {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hi img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ihi img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hi">
  <img alt="This shuould be an image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/1">
  <div class="ihi">
    <img alt="This shuould be inside of main image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I didn't have the images you were using, but I know you were using cats anyway :P

Comment: Wow, My image did have a cat!

Comment: @NewStudent Seriously? haha that was a joke. I'm sure there's a meme about cats on the internet somewhere :D

Answer (score 0):

set parent **`position:relative`** it works fine. if you didn't set parent position:relative ,it will relative to browser window.

```css
.hi{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  }
.hi img{
  position:absolute;
  left:25%;
  top:0%;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
}
.ihi img{
  position:absolute;
  left:25%;
  top:25%;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hi">
    <img alt="This shuould be an image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSUsk.jpg">
    <div class="ihi">
      <img alt="This shuould be inside of main image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0mrA.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OPs question. He wanted the left side of the second image to be 25% to the left of the left side of the first image.

Comment: @Vince   probably you have mistaken read this  "child element with class 'ihi' is always positioning w.r.t. the browser window instead of the parent image having class 'hi'."

Comment: Now I am confused... The element that has the class `hi` isn't an image at all. It's a `div`. It still seems to me like he wanted that second image to be positioned 25% to the left of the first image.

Comment: @vince that is your mistake ,he didn't requested for position the image, he want to position the div 'ihi' with 'hi'(parent) , instead positioning 'ihi' with **browser window **

Comment: I did misread that. I thought he only spoke about position of the images, but he does say "element", not "image". I'm still confused since his original CSS only targets the images and doesn't do anything with the divs. The parent element (div) doesn't position at all with regard to anything and neither does the child element because they're both divs without styles. Besides that, the divs are invisible (without the red background you added) and he can't see whether they're positioned correctly or not.

Comment: @Vince & Dream Hunter , I really wanted the second image to be positioned 25% to the left of the first image. However renaming old css to 'hi' only (without 'img') and then applying the first image with '.hi img' css with 100% width and height (i.e. as shown in the answers) solved the problem. So, hereby I have learned always create a separate css container for the parent item instead of directly putting the item.